# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'comp_owner'

Tags: python, flask

I am learning python with the below example code and facing the above error. Below is the code. I am using the class componentModel from models.py in the app.py code. and then passing the values to the front end. Not able to find where I am going wrong.

Models.py

```
class componentModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "component"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comp_name = db.Column(db.String())
    comp_owner = db.Column(db.String())

    def __init__(self, comp_name, comp_owner):
        self.comp_name = comp_name
        self.comp_owner = comp_owner
   
    def __repr__(self):
       return f"{self.comp_name}:{self.comp_owner}"

    @validates('name') 
    def validate_name(self, key, name):
      
      try:
        if not comp_name:
         comp_name="Not_Valid"
         raise AssertionError('No name provided')

        if componentModel.query.filter(componentModel.comp_name == comp_name).first():
         comp_name="Not_Valid"
         raise AssertionError('name is already in use')

        if len(comp_name) < 0 or len(comp_name) > 20:
          raise AssertionError('Username must be between 5 and 20 characters') 

        s= " @,#,$,%,!,&,^,*,(,),_,=,-"
        for ch in s:
          if ch in comp_name:
            comp_name="Not_Valid"
            raise AssertionError('Invalid country name')
            
      except AssertionError as msg:
        return msg
      else:
        return comp_name
```

App.py

```
@app.route('/component/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def componentadd():
    error_msg = ''
    success_msg = ''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('component/add.html')
        
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor.execute('SELECT Empnum,Employee_Name FROM empmaster') 
        empmaster_data = cursor.fetchall()     
        componentname = request.form['componentname']     
        componentowner = request.form['componentowner']
        comp_result = componentModel(comp_name=componentname)
        if str(comp_result) != componentname:
            return render_template('component/add.html', msg=comp_result)
        else:
            db.session.add(comp_result, componentowner)
        db.session.add(empmaster_data)
        db.session.commit()
        
        success_msg = 'Added successfully !'
        return redirect(url_for('componentlist'))
    return render_template('component/add.html', empmaster_data=empmaster_data, componentowner =componentowner)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor.execute('SELECT Empnum,Employee_Name FROM empmaster') 
        empmaster_data = cursor.fetchall()     
        componentname = request.form['componentname']     
        componentowner = request.form['componentowner']
        comp_result = componentModel(comp_name=componentname, comp_owner=componentowner)
...
```

Comment: this is working fine but the validator message is popping with values entered in the form. the if condition is not working after the code you mentioned. it is going to else part od the code.            if str(comp_result) != componentname:
            return render_template('component/add.html', msg=comp_result)
        else:
            db.session.add(comp_result)